# How to get the first cell's text in a row given a value from a column?

Tags: google-sheets

This is what my sheet looks like and I want to look through the first percentage in the rows labeled overall  (C6, C9, C12, C15) find the highest percentage and then return the corresponding grouping of that value. For example, if the highest percent was 31.43% (C12) I would get "-Information-"
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit] your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To make the data [queryable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/queryable), fill it down and then apply `filter()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  fillDown_, lambda(data, let(a,data,r,max(bycol(a,lambda(l,index(ifna(xmatch("?*",to_text(l),2,-1)))))),s,sequence(r),array_constrain(bycol(a,lambda(v,map(s,lambda(i,index(xlookup(i,s/(v<>""),v,,-1)))))),r,columns(a)))), 
    
  data, fillDown_(A2:C), 
  keys, choosecols(data, 3), 
  join(", ", filter(choosecols(data, 1), keys = max(keys))) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[bycol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032),
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914),
[sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)
and
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).